# xarray: compute daily anomalies from monthly resampled average (not the climatology)

Tags: python, python-xarray

xarray's [documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/weather-data.html#calculate-monthly-anomalies) explains how to compute anomalies to the monthly *climatology*. Here I am trying to do something slightly different: **from daily timeseries, I would like to compute the daily anomaly to this month's average** (not from the monthly climatology).

I managed to do it using groupby and a manualy created monthly stamp (code below). Is there a better, less hacky way to obtain the same result?

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create a data array
t = pd.date_range('2001', '2003', freq='D')
da = xr.DataArray(np.arange(len(t)), coords={'time':t}, dims='time')

# Monthly time stamp for groupby
da.coords['stamp'] = ('time', [str(y) + '-' + str(m) for (y, m) in 
                               zip(da['time.year'].values, 
                                   da['time.month'].values)])

# Anomaly
da_ano = da.groupby('stamp') - da.groupby('stamp').mean()

da_ano.plot();
```

[image: plot output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explicitly [resample](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations) the monthly time-series of means into a daily time-series. Example:

```
monthly = da.resample(time='1MS').mean()
upsampled_monthly = monthly.resample(time='1D').ffill()
anomalies = da - upsampled_monthly
```